# Better video thumbnails in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, video, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Are there any Windows Explorer extensions that allow the preview thumbnails to be more than just static images?

The preview generation in XP is based on the first frame, which is completely useless for most videos.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [workaround](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3353/Thumbnail_enable_custom_frame.zip) [Note: Zip file]. Found at [Neowin forums](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/490855-video-thumbnails-using-a-different-frame/page__st__15).

Comment: They were asking about using *animated* thumbnails like YouTube has (now, and porn sits had a long time ago; *sigh*) where the thumbnail image cycles through various parts of the video.